# Display on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to make a button display when it's click. I'm fairly close, can anyone give me some advice on how to improve it, so it'll work?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if( $("#btn").css('display', 'none') ) {
        $("#btn").click(function() ) {
            $("#info").css('display', 'block');
        )};
    } else { 
      $("#info").css('display', 'none'); 
    }       
});

    <div id="btn">
        <a class="help-a" href="#">help</a>
    </div> 
    <div id="info">
        <p>data goes here</p>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: If the button have `display: none`, how you will click it?

Comment: That's true, I tried a few approaches and wasn't getting anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`$.fn.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method: show if hidden, hide if visible:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#info").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my code. the actual button is an anchor tag of <a>. I tried $("#btn > a") and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you post HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

        $("#btn").click(function() ) {
             if( $("#btn").css('display') === "none" ) {
                   $("#info").css('display', 'block'); 
             } else { 
                   $("#info").css('display', 'none'); 
             }       
        )};

});
```

You were doing it right - Just minor code re-arrangement and a small update was needed.

Comment: .toggle or .show() / .hide() perhaps? And what to do if the button is hidden?

Comment: Thanks. I was about to bring these things in picture one by one.